# I would like to write an Excel VBA for the repeated itmes for several columns

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how to write the excel VBA for this repeated items as shown in the photo?
The left is the data I have, and the right is the target answer I want to achieve.
I tried to find the code for that but it is in vain, could anyone please help? thanks.

[image]

```
Sub repeat_items()

'----variables
Dim lrow_d As Long
Dim lrow_s As Long

'-----Sheets
Dim s_sht As Worksheet

'-----Define Sheet names
Set s_sht = Worksheets("Repeat")

'--LastRow
lrow_s = s_sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


'---Creating repeating
s_sht.Range("D2:D1000000").Clear

For i = 2 To lrow_s         'count no. 2 of column A from up to down

lrow_d = s_sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

s_sht.Range("A" & i).copy Destination:=s_sht.Range("D" & lrow_d + 1 & ":" & "D" & lrow_d + s_sht.Range("B" & i))
            '+1 is bottom next row      'D is the column D location         'B is calculating number of times from column B

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off your provided screenshot, something like this should work for you. Be sure to update worksheet name as necessary, and adjust the destination if you want it elsewhere. (Would need to add a new worksheet variable if you want the destination on a different sheet).

```
Sub repeat_items()
    
    'Declare and set variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rData As Range:     Set rData = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rDest As Range:     Set rDest = ws.Range("H2")
    If rData.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub  'No data
    Dim aData As Variant:   aData = rData.Value
    
    'Prepare results array
    Dim aResults() As Variant, iResult As Long
    ReDim aResults(1 To WorksheetFunction.Sum(rData), 1 To 1)
    
    'Prepare loop variables
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, sResult As String
    
    'Loop through each row
    For i = 2 To UBound(aData, 1)
        sResult = vbNullString      'Reset the result string to null
        
        'Loop through each column
        For j = 1 To UBound(aData, 2)
            
            'Check if the value in the data is a number or not
            If Not IsNumeric(aData(i, j)) Then
                'Not a number, add the text to the result string with an "_"
                sResult = sResult & aData(i, j) & "_"
            Else
                'This is a number, loop that number of times
                For k = 1 To aData(i, j)
                    'Each time, add this column header to the result string and append it to the results array
                    iResult = iResult + 1
                    aResults(iResult, 1) = sResult & aData(1, j)
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    rDest.Resize(rDest.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    rDest.Resize(UBound(aResults, 1)).Value = aResults  'Output results
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it helps me solve the problem :)